# Creating Interactive Venn Diagram in R

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am working on R to build interactive Venn Diagram. I am currently using the VennDiagram library to do this but to make an interactive Venn diagram is not possible with this library. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: This seems both off-topic for the lack of code to demonstrate teh inability with a particular package as well as too broad because it's essentially giving us a project to set up. complete, and document. Seems more appropriate for a consultation specification at market rates.

Comment: What do you call interactive ? You can have interaction with `RShiny` that refresh Venn Diagram on inputs

Comment: @Clemsang by interactive I mean pointer connection. When I hover the mouse pointer on a category it should go deeper into that category.

Comment: @ABHISHEKAGNIHOTRI I really don't know if this is possible. But you can have a conditionnal plot based on Shiny inputs to define category and plot the subselection only

Comment: @Clemsang It is really helpful. I have tried something similar and it worked. Thank you.